# Calculating time break in rate & work question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Working alone at their respective constant rates, Audrey can complete
>   a certain job in 4 hours, while Ferris can do the same job in 3 hours.
>   Audrey and Ferris worked together on the job and completed it in 2
>   hours, but while Audrey worked this entire time, Ferris worked for
>   some of the time and took 3 breaks of equal length. How many minutes
>   long was each of Ferris’s breaks?

My approach is

**Rate of A** = 1 unit of work in 4 hours = 1/4

**Rate of B** = 1 unit of work in 3 hours = 1/3

**Actual Ra + Rb** = 1/2 (given in question) or 1 unit of work in 2 hours (120mins)

**Ideal Ra + Rb** = (1/4)+(1/3)=(7/12)

Basically 7 unit of work in 12 hours or 1 unit of work in 1.71 hours (~102 mins)

Therefore I can conclude that (120-102 mins)18 mins time was wasted. Hence 6 minute break each.

But the answer is 10.

Can anyone guide me where am I going wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

So in 2 hours, Audrey would have completed 1/2 of the job as he takes 4 hours to complete the job. Ferris completed the remaining half in those 2 hours. But Ferris would normally complete 1/2 of the job in 3/2 = 1.5 hours. Thus we conclude that Ferris took break for 30 min and since he took 3 breaks of equal length, each break was 10 min long.

Hopefully this is clear now.

Comment: This was exactly copied [from](https://gmatclub.com/forum/audrey-4-hours-to-complete-a-certain-job-ferris-can-do-the-159032.html)

Comment: I read this answer from GMAT website but I couldn't get my head through it. Also can you pin point why/where MY logic is incorrect

Comment: Also, 0.3 hours = 18 minutes. Can you elaborate how you wrote `1/2`. And he took 3 breaks as mentioned in the question

Comment: 0.1 hour = 6 minutes not 10 min.